# Flutter: How to keep gesture events state after opening a simple dialog

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a grid of Images and I want to open a simple dialog when I long press an Image and to be closed automatically when my finger no longer contacts with the screen (like Instagram quick image preview).

I attached `LongPress` event to all the images and it works fine so a dialog opens up when I long press an image however when I put my finger up nothing happens even though I attached events like `onTapUp`, `onLongPressEnd`, `onPointerUp` Because of the new opened dialog, All of those events are lost and no longer fires up.

I tried to add the pointer up events to the opened dialog instead but there is a catch, I must tap and release again in order to make it work because Flutter unable to recognize that my finger is already in contact with screen and the opened dialog caused flutter to forget about this fact.

Comment: Very nice question! Would you add your code little bit please?

Comment: @HeavenOSK What kind of code do you expect? The full implementation is really complex, containing multiple layers of information holders etc. I explained the concept in my answer. Implementing it is really not that hard, but you need to store sizes and positions of widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert an [`OverlayEntry`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/OverlayEntry-class.html) into the `Overlay` stack by using [`Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry)`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/OverlayState/insert.html).

In this overlay, you can catch gestures when required and take actions accordingly. As overlays always sit on top of anything else, the dialog will not cancel your long press gesture and you will be able to respond to `longPressEnd`.

You will only need to calculate which image has been pressed or use the `Offset`'s provided by `onTapDown` and the position of the images.

To get the global position of your images, you can assign [`GlobalKey`'s](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) to your images and get their global positions in the following way:

```
final RenderBox renderBox = globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

final Offset position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
final Size size = renderBox.size;
```

To get the position of your long press, you will need to store the position of [`onTapDown`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/GestureTapDownCallback.html):

```
onTapDown: (details) => position = details.globalPosition
```

Now you have everything you need to figure out which bounds the long press happened in.

Comment: is any sample code to know haw can we implementing that?

Comment: @DolDurma you can check my code snippet below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63086452/1265915

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work. It can be done with `Overlay` Widget.

In the widget with `GestureDetector`, when `onLongPress` is called, create an `OverlayEntry` object with your dialog, and insert it into `Overlay`.

When `onLongPressEnd` is called, call the `remove` function of `OverlayEntry` object.

```
// Implement a function to create OverlayEntry
OverlayEntry getMyOverlayEntry({
  @required BuildContext context,
  SomeData someData,
}) {
  return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(child: SomeWidgetAgain());
      }
  );
}

// In the widget where you want to support long press feature
OverlayEntry myOverayEntry;

GestureDetector(
    onLongPress: () {
      myOverayEntry = getMyOverlayEntry(context: context, someData: someData);
      Overlay.of(context).insert(myOverayEntry);
    },
    onLongPressEnd: (details) => myOverayEntry?.remove(),

    child: SomeWidgerHere(),
)
```

Here's the gist on Github:

https://gist.github.com/plateaukao/79aa39854dc4eabf1220bdfa9a0334b6

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AnimatedContainer` and put a `GestureDetector` inside.
change width and height using `setState` and it's done.

```
Center(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          width: containerWidth,
          height: containerHeight,
          color: Colors.red,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: (){
              print("Long Press");
              setState(() {
                containerWidth = 200;
                containerHeight = 200;
              });
            },
            onLongPressUp: (){
              print("On Long Press UP");
              setState(() {
                containerWidth = 100;
                containerHeight = 100;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      )
```